# What is the size and name of mic input nut?

Tags: microphone, speakers, hardware, equipment, connector

In the below picture is the mic input missing a nut.

Does anyone know the size and name of such a nut?

[image: this]

Comment: Do you mean the one on the most left? It's 6.3 JACK, probably a balanced one (TRS), but may be unbalanced (TS) as well.

Comment: i think she means the ring around the jack input. but to be fairly honest, this is not a sound design question.. or do you think it is tohecz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the hardware that retains the jack, in the US it is a 3/8-32 jam nut. Most likely.